# How to monitore the stdout of a command with a timer?

Tags: bash, shell

I'd like to know when an application hasn't print a line in **stdout** for N seconds.

Here is a reproducible example:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
dmesg -w | {
  while IFS= read -t 3 -r line
  do
    echo "$line"
  done
  echo "NO NEW LINE"
}
echo "END"
```

I can see the `NO NEW LINE` but the pipe doesn't stop and the bash doesn't continue. `END` is never displayed.

- How to exit from the braces' code?

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117501/in-bash-script-how-to-capture-stdout-line-by-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to exit from the brackets' code?

Not all commands exit when they can't write to output or receive `SIGPIPE`, and they will not exit until they actually notice they can't write to output. Instead, run the command in the background. If the intention is *not* to `wait` on the process, in bash you could just use process substitution:

```
{ 
     while IFS= read -t 3 -r line; do
        printf "%s\n" "$line"
    done
    echo "end"
} < <(dmesg -w)
```

You could also use coprocess. Or just run the command in the background with a pipe and `kill` it when done with it.

Comment: Thanks! That works! How is the `dmesg -w` killed? Which signal is sent to "dmesg -w" command? Having SIGKILL would kill the parent not all the children of that process (we don't have access to that). SIGINT would be better to make sure everything is killed.

Comment: `How is the dmesg -w killed?` By bash in an unknown point, usually when command ends. `Which signal is sent to "dmesg -w" command?`  No idea, I think TERM.  `Having SIGKILL would kill the parent` I think it's not a problem, it should be sent to the process group, but I recommend testing it to be sure. Adding https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/609300/209955 or similar to the subprocess is also simple. But it would be strange - my strong guess is the whole process group should be killed.

Comment: I see, `dmesg -w` is still running even after bash returned. I will investigate more. Thanks!

Comment: I see that too. There are no rules for process substitution lifetimes and it's mostly "just works" kind of stuff. Use coprocess and kill it when done. After shell is killed, `dmesg` is killed too. Running it in separate shell might be the solution.

Comment: Wow ok.. I'll check how to use coprocess for that.